# Simple cURL request ignored by the server

Tags: php, curl

For days now I'm trying to make a connection to web server from remote server via cURL, and so far I failed. try to contacted my hosting company and they said the server already support cURL lib. Eventually I use simple way for testing it using codes below. `print_r($array);` always returning array without any parameter inside like this `Array()` when it should return with all parameters. I hope someone can have better understanding of this issue and provide an answer for it, many thanks.

**send.php** this in remote server

```
<?php
$number= '12345'; 
$status= 'SUCCESS'; 
$msg = 'Transaction is Success!'; 

$curlHandle = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mywebsite.org/test.php'); 
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'number='.$number.'&status='.$status.'&msg ='.$msg); 
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curlHandle,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));

if (!curl_exec($curlHandle)) {
echo 'An error has occurred: ' . curl_error($curlHandle); 
} 
else { 
echo 'everything was successful'; 
} 

$array = curl_exec($curlHandle);

print_r($array);

curl_close($curlHandle);
?>
```

**test.php** this in web server

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: `curl_exec` cannot return `array`. it returns `string` or `boolean`

Comment: You call `curl_exec()` _twice_! Why? And it certainly does not directly return an array as you appear to expect. Read the fine manual: http://se2.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: @hindmost you suggest how can receive back the parameter that i send?

Comment: the manual said like this `However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.` so it should return array with parameter inside.

Comment: @arkascha yes you're right i shoud delete the first `curl_exec()`. cos i got an error warning.

Answer (score 0):

Less is more.
This may work for you :

```
<?php
$number= '12345'; 
$status= 'SUCCESS'; 
$msg = 'Transaction is Success!'; 

$curlHandle = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mywebsite.org/test.php'); 
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'number='.$number.'&status='.$status.'&msg ='.$msg); 
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$html = curl_exec($curlHandle);
curl_close($curlHandle);
echo($html);

?>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer i've try it but still doesn't return any parameter

Comment: because it's an array you may have to check the source code, for ex, in firefox `ctrl+u`, if not please provide the real url so we can test it.